# How to Sort a List by Sublist containing Integers

Tags: java

So if you have this:

```
List<Integer> subList;
    for example contains: [0, 6] or [2, 6] , [7, 6]
        [[0, 6], [2, 6], [7, 6]]
List<List> list;
    contains subLists: [0, 6], [2, 6], [7, 6] or [55, 4], [57, 5], [58, 5]
        [[[0, 6], [2, 6], [7, 6]], [[55, 4], [57, 5], [58, 5]]]
```

How do you sort the List on the second value of the subList ascendingly. you can assume that the other values in other subLists are considerably far away from the previous or next subList. There are no values the same from subList to subList.

into the following:

```
[[[55, 4], [57, 5], [58, 5]], [[0, 6], [2, 6], [7, 6]]]
```

Comment: You are familiar with comparators?

Comment: Could you perhaps add more details regarding the desired sort behaviour? At least for me it's kind of hard to understand how the sort is supposed to work...

Answer (score 0):

use comparators:

```
Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<T> c)
```

and build your comparator accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comparator that sorts based on the content of the sublist:

1. Make sure all sublists are sorted in descending order (your example seems to reflect this requirement):

   `list.forEach(sublist -> Collections.sort(sublist.sort(Collections.reverseOrder())));`
2. Sort the outer list based on the first element of the sublist

   `Collections.sort(list, (sublistone, sublisttwo) -> sublistone.get(0).compareTo(sublisttwo.get(0)));`

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(), new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {
    public int compare(final List<Integer> o1, final List<Integer> o2) {
        return o1.get(1) - o2.get(1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys I pretty much just figured it out by typing it out. Little more background. I am working with pixel data. x and y as the inner lists values. there are groups of pixels that are far from each other bus some are at the same height or at a different x. But i want to sort on the height.

it went as follows:

```
public List<List> sortSubList(final List<List> areas) {
    List<List> sorted = new ArrayList<>();
    conuloop:
    for (List<List> area : areas) {
        if (sorted.contains(area)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            if (sorted.isEmpty()) {
                sorted.add(area);
            } else {
                int pos = 1;
                for (List<List> sortArea : sorted) {
                    if ((int) sortArea.get(0).get(1) <= (int) area.get(0).get(1)) {
                        sorted.add(pos, area);
                        continue conuloop;
                    } else {
                       pos += 1;
                    }
                }
                sorted.add(0, area);
             }
        }
    }
    return sorted;
}
```

If you guys have any suggestions to make this more efficient and less time consuming, because this has to go over a lot of data. I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: stick to comparator

Answer (score 0):

More generally, Using a comparator, you could do something like:

```java
List<ArrayList<Integer>>> integers = new ArrayList<>();
Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>>> minIntegerComparator = Comparator.comparing(k->k.stream().min((v1,v2)->v1.compareTo(v2)).get());
                
Collections.sort(integers, minIntegerComparator);
```

which finds the minimum value in each sublist and compares against those to sort the main list.

Note that if a value is null, or if a sublist is empty/null, this may fail -  but you can mitigate using things like `.orElseGet(()->0)` instead of `.get()` to provide default values